# mySQL stored procedure error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to use a if statement in my stored mySQL procedure, but when I try to create it in mySQL workbench I get this error `ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database'.'table' WHERE date=dateIn;`.

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`rates_d_db` PROCEDURE `byDate`(in dateIn VARCHAR(255),in action VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

IF action = "edit" THEN EDIT `database`.`table` WHERE date=dateIn;

ELSE SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE date=dateIn;

END IF;

END$$
```

I am new to stored procedures, so it's probably a very noob mistake.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: what you want to use in edit, It is wrong (EDIT `database`.`table` WHERE date=dateIn;) . Do you want here update or alter statement.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL. You will have to wrap that in backticks as well.

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong, but this is what I did, and still no luck... `'table'.'column'`, where the ' are backticks.

Comment: You wrapped the `date` in `WHERE date=dateIn` in backticks?

Comment: I did yes, like so `'date'=dateIn`

Comment: @user you need to use backticks `

Comment: I did, as stated above, if I use the backticks in the commenting section, it highlights the text, so I can't use it in here, but I am using these -> `

Comment: @user hmm, strange. Then I don't know what it is

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct version of your procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`rates_d_db` PROCEDURE `byDatee`(in dateIn VARCHAR(255),in action VARCHAR(255))
       BEGIN
           IF action = "edit" THEN 
                -- I used select below as i don't know what you want in edit either alter table or update table
               SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE date=dateIn;    
           ELSE
                SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE date=dateIn;
           END IF;
END $$
```